A TV show similar to Pokemon with teens chasing creatures
I'm looking for a TV series that was shown on Spanish TV at one point between 2011 and 2013 (but it wasn't Spanish) . It was animated, but I don't know if it was an anime.
It had creatures similar to those on Pokemon, and they also fought on battles. The characters used cards to call them, and every character had their own device to use the cards (the main character had a gun, another one a watch...).
I remember that the creatures appeared in our world when a scientific experiment went wrong and our two dimensions fused. In the first episode, the main characters (that were teenagers) were supposed to help a scientist to capture one of those creatures that was destroying the city. The main characters were a girl, the typical clever boy, and an irresposinble boy that no one took seriously. So the scientist gave a gun that could use the cards to the "clever boy" because he was the most responsible.
They find the creature, they try to fight but the gun doesn't obey the clever boy's orders, and they are about to lose when the irresponsible boy realises that the creature is not aggressive, it had hurt his throat. He cures it, and they realise that he is the only one who can use the gun.
I don't remember anything else except that the irresponsible boy had a creature which was his bestfriend, like Ash and Pikachu,and they both loved doughnouts. In the last episode, our dimensions separate and the I.B. runs away because he doesn't want to say goodbye to his bestfriend, but he finds a doughnout and returns on time to give it to him and watch him disappear while he promises him that he'll find a way to meet him again.
(BTW, it's not Yu-Gi-Oh!)

Beyblade was also the one which was having creatures in the blade

There's Bakugen and Digimon, but no one had unique devices.

@cde Dear god there are a lot of these...

You're looking for Mix Master from 2005.

The series takes place in the town of Camebridge where, through the accidental opening of a portal from the fictional Mix Master video game world of Atreia, the peaceful little town is invaded by the funny and sometimes dangerous game creatures, known as "hench", as well as the game world's evil Prince Brad. The main protagonist, 11-year-old Ditt Lee, is given a card mixer by the eccentric Dr. Joeb, and now must "mix" those hench (as learned from the fictional video game) to achieve peace and safety throughout the series, while he grows into his destiny to become the one true "Mix Master".

That card mixer looks like a gun, the group is like you described it (clever boy, reckless boy & a girl) and the hero has a pet 'hench' called Pachi and is obsessed with donuts. Here's the first episode, where they chase a 'hench' when Ditt suddenly realizes that it just has something lodged in its throat (a pile of garbage, to be precise, tied to an old bicycle, in an apparent attempt to provoke the ire of Pokemon creators and Studio Ghibli in one fell swoop). This convinces the scientist, who originally gave the card mixer to the clever boy, to give it to Ditt instead:




Apparently this thing aired on Cartoon Network in the US? Never even heard of it.

No one in their right mind should know all of them. ;)

I'm just surprised it made it on air with the gun, for the target audience. Toonami used to edit heavily.
